# Do i need add INDEX in mysql for GROUP_CONCAT?

Tags: mysql, indexing, group-concat

for example

```
GROUP_CONCAT(scpc.spage_t SEPARATOR '|') AS compl_titles,
GROUP_CONCAT(scpc.spage_sku SEPARATOR '|') AS compl_skus,
```

Do i need to add INDEXES for spage_t and spage_sku for speed up MYSQL?

Comment: The important index will be on the column you use in `GROUP BY`.

Comment: *Do i need to add INDEXES for spage_t and spage_sku for speed up MYSQL?* For shown queries - no. Until the index is covering.

Answer (score 0):

No.  An index on just the column(s) in `GROUP_CONCAT` would probably be totally useless.

On the other hand, a "composite" and/or "covering" index *may* provide a performance benefit.

We need to see

- The query
- `EXPLAIN SELECT ...`
- `SHOW CREATE TABLE`